# How can I install Ubuntu to a spare second hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

I have recently purchased 'Ubuntu unleashed' with a view to making a first time installation of Ubuntu.  The book contained a DVD version 13.10 but I have so far been unsuccessful with the actual installation itself

I am attempting to instal the program on a spare second SSD (D:) 
- my other SSD has Windows 7 (C:).

I am unable to find a way to inform the installation to instal Ubuntu onto the second drive (D:).

It will install itself perfectly well onto the remaining space on C: (but of course I don't want it there). At the very beginning of the set up, in the 3 choices, which ever I choose I never see an option to choose the final destination - drive D:

The dual boot installs itself beautifully but both OS's are on the same drive!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

During install, it should give you an option to partition the drive yourself. It's in the step where it asks if it should install next to Windows, option is called "Something else". In that option, you can select your drive (ie. either /dev/sda og /dev/sdb).

Answer (score 0):

During the install you have the option to partition the disk and choose the right partitions for your install. You just have to choose it and manually do it (choose the right place to install).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any of the auto install options, just disconnect the Windows hard drive temporarily. Then Ubuntu installer will only have choice to install to the SSD drive you want.

Or as suggested by others you can use Something else or manual install. But then you have to create partitions minimum of / (root) and swap, although with SSD and if you have lots of RAM, swap may not be required, but probably will not be used anyway.  For / partition you need to select format as ext4, tick format box. Also below partitioning screen is a combo box. It defaults to the drive that is sda, you want to change it to the drive that is sdb, or else you overwrite the Windows boot loader in sda. Then set BIOS to boot from the sdb drive.

If your Windows is UEFI (most Windows 7 are BIOS) you will want to install in UEFI mode and how you boot installer is how it installs.

Answer (score -2):

well, what I found is that: make shure you can see the drive in file explorer. If you cant, turn it on in the boot menu, and under... I think drives. you should be given a list of things plugged into the inside of your pc. dvd roms, graphics processor, and hard drives, for examples. turn them all on, then launch windows as usual. Do what you described in your problem, and every thing should be fine. this SHOULD work regardless of if you have the physical copy, or downloadable copy. if this isn't your issue, sorry, but I can't help you.
EDIT: if you don't see it, plug the 5 cord thing into both drives, then use a spare orange flat cable to plug the new drive to the mother board, like the blue cord, but in a black motherboard input.